# How to kill all sessions for a Linux user except first one, and limit users to one login session

Tags: linux, kill

I need to know how to kill all processes for a logged in user except the first one in linux redhat 6.

for example, `AZain` user is logged in multiple times from different machines so I need to allow only the first process and kill all others for this user:

```
who -u
AZain    pts/2        2016-06-23 08:34   .         27191 (localhost)
AZain    pts/4        2016-06-23 09:01   .         28885 (localhost)
root     pts/0        2016-06-23 08:14   .         25962 (10.11.155.23)
AZain    pts/1        2016-06-23 08:34 00:27       27169 (10.11.155.23)
AZain    pts/3        2016-06-23 09:01   .         28867 (10.11.155.14)
```

Edit: I am trying to do so as I am having an application in which consumes licenses for users. So every new session for the same user would consume more license. If I could prevent any new logins for the same user that would be great.

Comment: Specifically interactive shell sessions? Or do you mean "processes"?

Comment: It's not entirely reliable, but since PIDs are generally assigned in ascending order, you could look for the lowest shell PID and kill everything other than it owned by the user in question.

Comment: @DopeGhoti "Not entirely reliable"?! With PID wrap-around this is terrible advice, especially on a multi-user machine. Also, although the OP states "Linux", as a general solution, this would definitely not work on e.g. OpenBSD (random PIDs).

Comment: @Kusalananda yes I mean processes which could be get by who -u

Comment: @AhmedZein please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/291548/edit) your post and show example of your command output.

Comment: @Rahul  I need to kill all other process for AZain user for example and allow only the first process for him.

who -u
AZain    pts/2        2016-06-23 08:34   .         27191 (localhost)
AZain    pts/4        2016-06-23 09:01   .         28885 (localhost)
root     pts/0        2016-06-23 08:14   .         25962 (10.11.155.23)
AZain    pts/1        2016-06-23 08:34 00:27       27169 (10.11.155.23)
AZain    pts/3        2016-06-23 09:01   .         28867 (10.11.155.14)

Comment: @AhmedZein try updated answer

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for wanting to do this. It seems awfully anti-social to boot a user from a system like this, possibly causing her to lose data. If you restricted it to shell sessions that were idle and had no child processes, then it may possibly be an idea.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok I need to do this as I am having an application that consume licenses for users. So multiple logins for the same user would consume more licenses and I need to allow 1 session per user only so that only one could be logged in by same username.

Comment: Aha! This is information that may prompt a totally different answer! Instead of killing started processes (and possibly losing data), one could instead stop the spawning of new shell sessions...  I'm on a bus at the moment, so won't be able to give a proper answer right now.

Comment: @Kusalananda That would be good. But how could I do that?

Comment: Update the question with this new info. I'll think on it over the day and I might give an answer in 12h or so if nobody else has solved it by then. Also, search for "limit number of user login sessions"  or similar here on this forum, or on ServerFault (or SuperUser).

Comment: By the way, does just  logging in cause a license to be used, or is it a particular application that does this? In the latter case, you could write a wrapper script around the application...

Comment: Just logging in causes a license to be used in this application.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to think, and life has been happening here. Can at the moment only refer to two similar questions on ServerFault (you might have found these yourself already). Hopefully, they are helpful (let me know): http://serverfault.com/questions/546261/limit-logons-per-user-account-in-linux  http://serverfault.com/questions/367906/how-do-i-limit-concurrent-session-on-a-per-user-basis-for-ssh

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - you're trying to limit the number of instances of licensed software being run per user, but you're focused on limiting shell logins.  This is the wrong problem to solve.

A better solution is:

- Rename the program, e.g. from `/usr/local/bin/foo` to `/usr/local/bin/foo.real`
- Write a wrapper script with the same name and path as the original program (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/foo`) to check if the user is already running it.

  If yes, exit with an appropriate error message.  If not, run the original program (`/usr/local/bin/foo.real`)

A very simple example:

```
#! /bin/sh

if pgrep -u "$USER" foo.real >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  echo "You are already running foo" >&2
  exit 1
else
  foo.real
fi
```

Note: This works for well-behaved users who understand the licensing issue and don't mind following the rules.  It will not stop a sneaky user from running `foo.real` themselves.  You could stop sneaky but not very bright users by adding `alias foo.real=foo` to `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

You could run a root cron job which detected instances of `foo.real` being run that did not have a shell script called `foo` as the parent process.  The cron job could kill any such instances and/or email you a warning (to avoid spamming yourself, keep track of the process IDs for foo.real and don't mail yourself multiple warnings about the same PID).

---

BTW, if your licensed software comes with some kind of license manager, check its documentation to see if it can restrict the number of instances per user.

Comment: The OP says "Just logging in causes a license to be used in this application."  But you're right, there might be something in the license manager that can be tweaked.

Comment: @Kusalananda - yes, he did say that, I didn't notice that until you pointed it out.  However, given the confusion of the OP and his inability to clearly express what he means and what he wants, I'm going to assume that he's mistaken on that point.  In any case, this answer is still useful for applications with either no license limitations (but a wish to limit resource usage) or less insane limits - merely logging in shouldn't trigger use of a license, actually running the app should.

Comment: It *could* be that he means "logging into" the application, i.e. starting it and entering some credentials or something. Anyway, XY.

Comment: yeah, that's what i assumed he meant.